# TensorForest categorical features

Tags: python, tensorflow, random-forest, categorical-data

It looks like TensorForest, the Random Forest implementation inside TensorFlow, somehow supports categorical features as input (without one-hot encoding).

See

- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest/python/ops/data_ops.py#L32
- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4025#issuecomment-242814047

However it's not clear how to use them.

If you look at this example

- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/random_forest_mnist.py

the 'x' parameter at line 65

- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/random_forest_mnist.py#L65

must be a float array.

How could I pass categorical features (e.g. strings)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the SKCompat wrapper to the estimator, the 'x' and 'y' parameters do need to be floats (because with that interface you can only pass in one object).   However, using the estimator's input function interface (input_fn=...) that most examples use, the feature dictionary that input_fn returns can be a mix of floats, int, and string Tensors.  Floats are treated as continuous, ints and strings are treated as categorical (creating x[i] == T decision nodes instead of x[i] <= T) and no one-hot encoding is needed.  So you need to create an input function that returns batches of data (which is what the SKCompat interface does for you essentially).